# html5 video with multiple source files and multiple text tracks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a video element and the user can select which video they would like to play from a list of options. For each video I have one text track that is associated with it. I can play the newly selected video easily. But I can't seem to be able to set the new text track.

In the html I have:

```
<video id="theVideo" controls="" width="569" height="288">
    <track id="theTrack" kind="subtitles" type="text/webvtt" srclang="en" />
</video>
```

I have tried adding the source like this:

```
$('#theTrack').attr('src', newSource.vtt);
```

This just builds up the different subtitles so I end up with lots of different subtitles from the previous videos being displayed at the same time.

I have also tried removing the track all together and adding it back on. This works except if I hide the captions and then select a new video to play. The whole page crashes after a short while of playing...I think it's still trying to display the old track text??

```
$('#theTrack').remove();
$('#theVideo').append("<track id='theTrack' kind='subtitles' type='text/webvtt' srclang='en'/>");
$('#theTrack').attr('src', newSource.vtt);
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!! 
Thanks

Comment: can you remove the entire video element from the DOM and recreate it, including the new .vtt source?

Comment: also can you pre-define all the text tracks on the original video source and swap them as needed when you change video source? or (harder work) read the text track and and insert the cues manually

Answer (score 0):

okay... so it's not pretty but it seems the way you need to go is to remove all the currently active cues from the video (and for some reason it seems to only work in reverse order) and then swap the source.

this sample works okay in Chrome, I did see one crash in Safari and IE9 was flaky but I'm not sure what your target platform(s) are. Looks like it really needs a bit of refinement in this area, but hopefully this will get you closer to where you need to be...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Toggle Caption Source</title>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay controls muted id="video">
    <source src="Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track id="t" src="botrack.vtt" label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" default> 
    HTML5 video not supported
</video>

<p onclick="o();">toggle</p>
<script>
function o() {
    var v = document.getElementById("video")
    var t = document.getElementById("t")

    var textTracks = v.textTracks; // one for each track element
    var textTrack = textTracks[0]; // corresponds to the first track element

    var cues = textTrack.cues;
    for (var i=cues.length;i>=0;i--) {
        textTrack.removeCue(cues[i]);
    }
    if (t.src == "http://{qualified.url}/botrack.vtt") {
        t.src = "http://{qualified.url}/entrack.vtt"
    } else {
        t.src = "http://{qualified.url}/botrack.vtt"
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```