# Remove all other 'vtt cues' from video tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video tag in which I pass video data i.e `src` and `vtt` dynamically,  I want to keep vtt for the current video only, and remove all other `textTracks`.

Right Now on switching the video, all vtt related to previously played videos start playing inside the video tag.

*vtt is subtitle*

```
     function addVttInvideo(data) {
        // http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/
        // https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2015/02/javascript/dynamically-adding-text-tracks-to-html5-video
        var video = document.getElementById('videoSrc');
        var track = video.addTextTrack('subtitles', 'English', 'en');
        track.mode = "showing";
        var startTime = parse_timestamp(data.info.start);
        var endTime = parse_timestamp(data.info.end);
        var cue = new VTTCue(startTime, endTime, data.info.text);

        // track.addEventListener("cuechange", function () {
        //   // get current cue, and remove it if it's number 2
        //   var currentCue = track.activeCues[0];
        //   track.removeCue(currentCue)
        // },false);
        track.addCue(cue);
        // console.log('subtitle.innerHTML',subtitle.innerHTML);
        // quick_and_dirty_vtt_or_srt_parser(subtitle.innerHTML).map(function(cue) {
        //     track.addCue(cue);
        // });
        // track.addCue(quick_and_dirty_vtt_or_srt_parser(2,55,'my profile'));


      }

      function parse_timestamp(s) {
        var match = s.match(/^(?:([0-9]{2,}):)?([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9][.,][0-9]{0,3})/);
        if (match == null) {
          throw 'Invalid timestamp format: ' + s;
        }
        var hours = parseInt(match[1] || "0", 10);
        var minutes = parseInt(match[2], 10);
        var seconds = parseFloat(match[3].replace(',', '.'));
        return seconds + 60 * minutes + 60 * 60 * hours;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('the exception album ' + e);
    }
// load video is called when user swipe next and back
function loadVideo(way) {
  var videoSrc = $('#videoSrc');
  if (way === 'prev') {
    videoCounter = videoCounter - 1;
    if (videoCounter < 0) videoCounter = VideoData.length - 1;
    videoSrc.attr('src', VideoData[videoCounter].vurl);
    videoSrc.attr('poster', VideoData[videoCounter].turl)
    addVttInvideo(VideoData[videoCounter].vtt)
  } else if (way === 'next') {
    videoCounter = videoCounter + 1;
    if (videoCounter > VideoData.length - 1) videoCounter = 0;
    videoSrc.attr('src', VideoData[videoCounter].vurl);
    videoSrc.attr('poster', VideoData[videoCounter].turl)
    addVttInvideo(VideoData[videoCounter].vtt)
  } else {
    videoSrc.attr('src', VideoData[0].vurl);
    videoSrc.attr('poster', VideoData[0].turl)
    addVttInvideo(VideoData[0].vtt)
    // document.getElementById('vsrc').onloadeddata = function() {
    //   debugger
    //
    // };
  }
  $("#videoAlbumCaption").text(videoCounter + 1 + " / " + VideoData.length);
}
```

Comment: Cannot close it, due to the bounty, but surely you must know already that you at least has to show what you have tried already. The question itself also doesn't provide with much info on what's the setup is, and how it all gets dynamically loaded. If you would at least provide with a [mcve] there might be something that could be answered, now it is for me all theoretical. Also since you are passing in stuff dynamically, you should theoretically be in control

Comment: You may be interested in [Delete a TextTrack from a video](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29306931/215552) and [html5 video with multiple source files and multiple text tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15215415/215552).

Comment: @Icepickle I have tried the commented part, in my 'addVttInvideo' function. Please see

Answer (score 3):

A bit confusing as your question is for removing vtt cue, but from what you described is removing all other textTracks.

I will explain how to remove all other textTracks.

HTML

```
<video src="foo.ogv">
    <track kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="subtitles_en.vtt" srclang="en" default>
    </track>
    <track kind="subtitles" label="Deutsche Untertitel" src="subtitles_de.vtt" srclang="de">
    </track>
</video>
```

videoElement.textTracks console output

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
console.log(videoElement);

TextTrackList {0: TextTrack, 1: TextTrack, length: 2, onchange: null, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null}
0: TextTrack {kind: "subtitles", label: "English subtitles", language: "en", id: "", mode: "showing", …}
1: TextTrack {kind: "subtitles", label: "Deutsche Untertitel", language: "de", id: "", mode: "disabled", …}
length: 2
```

**Remove Track**

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
videoElement.removeChild(videoElement.children[0]); //remove English subtitle


// you need iterlate videoElement.textTracks and find index according to language
var i =0;
var targetLanguage = "de";
for (let track of videoElement.textTracks){
    if(track.language !== targetLanguage){
        videoElement.removeChild(videoElement.children[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

As @Heretic Monkey commented, please refer to this for TextTrackList Implementation.
[Delete a TextTrack from a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306931/delete-a-texttrack-from-a-video/57881151#57881151)

Comment: It din't work for me, I have to do it other way 
```var video = document.getElementById('videoSrc');
    for (var i =0; i< video.textTracks.length; i++){
      video.textTracks[i].mode="disabled"
    }
    var track = video.addTextTrack('subtitles', 'English', 'en');
    track.mode = "showing";
    var startTime = parse_timestamp(data.info.start);
    var endTime = parse_timestamp(data.info.end);
    var cue = new VTTCue(startTime, endTime, data.info.text);
```